# How to enable confirmation alert when using 'rm' command to delete files / folders?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line, rm

I have found that we cannot recover files/folders when deleted using `rm` command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721491/how-to-recover-the-deleted-files-using-rm-r-command-in-linux-server)

But, is it possible to add a confirmation alert when using `rm` command in the `terminal`?

Comment: Have you tried `rm -i`

Comment: If you forget this on a command just do `rm --help` and you'll have all the answers right there.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use the `-i` flag:

```
rm -i someFile.txt
```

If you're concerned you may forget to do this, you could alias the `rm` command:

```
alias rm="rm -i"
```

If you place this alias in one of the files sourced when you start a session (e.g., `.bashrc`), you'll have it available in all your future terminal sessions.

Answer (score 21):

You want to use `rm -i` or `rm -I`

According to the man pages: `man rm`

> -i prompt before every removal
>
> -I prompt once before removing more than three files, or when removing recursively.  Less intrusive than -i, while still giving protection against most mistakes

Comment: Sad to say I don't have the `-I` option on mac os

Comment: @Juddling: I think you can use [safe-rm](http://macappstore.org/safe-rm/) instead.

Comment: Maybe you can use coreutils (brew install coreutils)!

Answer (score 3):

As above or perhaps

```
alias rm="rm -i"
```

But be careful doing this if you use multiple accounts and one does not have this alias