# Recovery of file deleted by rm -rf from Server running on Arch

Tags: archlinux, rm

Accidentally I have deleted few files using rm -rf command.
Is there is any way to recover those files.
I need them.

Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Recover from back-up? You do have a back-up, right? Otherwise this is a valuable lesson.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721491/how-to-recover-the-deleted-files-using-rm-r-command-in-linux-server

Comment: More related: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8696/what-to-do-with-the-rm-rf-hoax-question

Answer (score 1):

Install `foremost`

```
sudo apt-get install foremost
```

Take a look at `man foremost` to learn how to use foremost.

First make an empty writable directory to save recover files in a partition other than that you are going to recover.

Then run foremost.

I am going to recover my home partition ( let's say /dev/sda5).

$ sudo foremost -t jpg -i /dev/sda5 -o /recovery/data
Finally set user permission to /recovery/data/ to view image. type

```
$ sudo chown YOUR_USER_NAME /recovery/data -R
```

Some important foremost command line arguments.

```
-i  :- partition/image to recover
-o :- location to store recovered files.
-t  :- built in file filter options.  you can give multiple filters by separating using commas. (e.g: for jpg and pdf: -t jpg,pdf ) 
-q :- quick mode.
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/604320/538882)

Also refer : [Recover Your Deleted Files In Ubuntu | The easy way.](http://ubuntumanual.org/posts/357/recover-your-deleted-files-in-ubuntu)

Comment: [archlnix wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Foremost) and [package link](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=foremost) just for completeness.  Manish tagged the question `archlinux`, i guess, giving these links next to the `apy-get` install would be a plus.