# I removed ~/.config/plasma* config file.....so how should I get it back?

Tags: linux, kde-plasma

I removed `~/.config/plasma*` config file.

So how should I get it back?
Due to these I'm loosing all my customisation's done on desktop... F.e. wallpaper turns default after saving it previously.

Comment: Sorry for your pain, but StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for [unix.se] or [su], but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover the deleted files using "rm -R" command in linux server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721491/how-to-recover-the-deleted-files-using-rm-r-command-in-linux-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restore the file from your backups.

Comment: i dont have backup